# Snap : Overwriting a configuration file from a snap application

Tags: snap

Good morning,

I've installed the snap "intellij-idea-ultimate", and I would like to modify the configuration file "/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/current/bin/idea64.vmoptions" with custom entries.

I've copied this file in my user snap directory : "/home//snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/common/bin".

However, when I start the application, the parameter set (Xmx here) is not changed.

Is there limitation about what file you can modify and do I only rely on what configuration was planned to be configurable by the user? For example, here, could just set the file in ~/.IntelliJIdea2017.3/config, but if developers didn't thought of some configuration/other files, can I overwrite it from my ~/snap folder ?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/17221838.
Maybe it reads idea.vmoptions instead?